# Assets revisioning using angular custom builder

Tags: angular, caching, webpack, assets

From [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61607242/4134335), I am trying to use a `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser` with a custom Webpack config that uses html-loader and file-loader in order to rename asset files with their hash content as well as each reference to them in the source code.

The final purpose is to be able to cache the assets on in the browser but to guarantee that the user will always have the latest version of the asset (because if it changes due to a new release, the name of the asset will change too).

I started from the Angular Tour of Heroes guide (https://angular.io/tutorial) and did the following steps:

(in dashboard.component.html I added)

```
...
<img src="assets/angular-logo.png" />
...
```

I then added `src/assets/angular-logo.png`

I changed the `angular.json` file to use a custom builder

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser", <------------- (changed this)
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "customWebpackConfig": { <---------------------------------------- (added this)
            "path": "custom-webpack.config.js"
          },
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb",
              "maximumError": "10kb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    ...
}
```

Then I created `custom-webpack.config.js` at the root of the application:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
                exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['html-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    outputPath: 'assets/',
                    name: '[name].[contenthash].[ext]',
                },
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and i npm installed all the required loaders as well as `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`.

From what I understand, when I run `ng build --prod`, this will (on top of the existing Angular Webpack config)

1. Load TypeScript files (using `awesome-typescript-loader`)
2. Load templateUrl and styleUrls from Angular components (using `angular2-template-loader`)
3. Load HTML files
4. Load image files and rename them as assets with their content hash

The problem is that when I run `ng build --prod` it does not seem to work as the asset image name is still angular-logo.png in dist/assets.

I feel like there is something I don't understand about the way Webpack works. What I am missing?

Comment: Webpack will only handle things that are *actually referenced in the bundle* - the file loader for images only works if you use e.g. `import imgSrc from "path/to/assets/angular-logo.png";` then use the `imgSrc`. Like [this](https://github.com/textbook/react-ts-fe/blob/master/src/App.tsx?ts=2) (in React, but the same principle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to delete assets property in angular.json and like jonrsharpe said bring them via loaders in `import` statement. Now you need the right loaders to be activated on them.
2. Angular puts its own loaders on your .component.css/.component.html/component.ts files,
   so **when your webpack.config.js does not export a function - you
   automatically delete angular loaders**

   You need to apply angular loaders  (*ngtools/webpack/src/index.js*)
   on your src files:

   *custom-webpack.config.js*:

   ```
   module.exports = function (angularConfig) {
        let rules = angularConfig.module.rules || [];

        // feel free to take some rules off, or change the path that they apply on
        // Picking up only Angular core rules from Angular default webpack config.
        angularConfig.module.rules = [
           ...rules.filter(rule => rule.test.source.match(/@angular|\.js/)),
           ...rules.filter(rule => rule.test.source.match(/\.(css|scss|less|styl)/)).map(rule => util.replaceRawLoader(util.excludeUnnecessarryPaths(rule))),
           ...rules.filter(rule => rule.test.source.match(/\.tsx\?/)).map(rule => util.excludeUnnecessarryPaths(rule))
        ];

         return merge(angularConfig, { /* your webpack configuration */ });
   }
   ```

   For convenience, I purpose to put a breakpoint and debug this code.